# Whenever i type include zero as an input, it doesn't run

Tags: c

**This program converts binary to octal**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main (){
    int num, i, j;
    
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    int temp1 = 0;
    int temp2 = 0;
    int oct = 0;
    int nw; 
    
    for (i = 0; num != 0; i++){ 
        nw = num%1000;
        
        
        printf("\ni: %d \nnw: %d\n", i, nw);
        for (j = 0; nw != 0; j++){
                if (nw%10==1){
                temp1 += (po1w(2, j));
                nw/=10;
                }
            }
            
        temp2 = temp1 * pow(10,i); 
            
        printf("\nOct for now: %d\n", temp2);
        
        oct += temp2;
        
        temp1 = 0;
        temp2 = 0;
        num/=1000;
        
    
    }
    
    printf("\nThe Octal is %d", oct);
};
```

**But whenever it is ran, it doesn't except when the inputted numbers are just few binary numbers and without zero, but whenever it has zero in the binary it doesn't run at all**

Comment: Program doesn't compile with po1w typo.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what the problem. What input is the input that cause trouble and explain what the problem is.

Comment: Your inner loop only modifies `nw` if it encounters a 1. And so, if it encounters a 0, then you will keep looping forever, because the condition `nw != 0` is not met. You should _always_ divide by 10, not just when you encounter a 1. Move that last line out of the `if` block. I know that programming can sometimes seem daunting, but understand that the computer does exactly what you tell it. So you should be able to take a step back, read through your code one line at a time and figure out exactly what it does to your data. Going one step further, you can do this at runtime with a debugger.

Comment: Is your input decimal (123)?  Why do you process `num%1000;` at a time?

Comment: @AllanWind And here I've spent decades thinking that binary **is** octal... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 Input is not validated, and question is hard to grok so I wanted to make that op didn't just mean 0 and 1 in decimal when saying binary.  If input is expected to binary then why say it like that.  Anyways, I give up... and bow out.

Comment: @AllanWind `"%o\n"` anyone??? `:-)`... Another day... `:-)`

Comment: Probably a programming exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I actually solved it. The problem lies inside the nested loop, if statement,

```
 for (j = 0; nw != 0; j++){
        if (nw%10==1){
        temp1 += (po1w(2, j));
        nw/=10;
        }
    }
```

Instead of

```
for (j = 0; nw != 0; j++){
            if (nw%10==1){
            temp1 += (po1w(2, j));
            }
            nw /= 10;
        }
```

Comment: The poor formatting makes your code to read.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I dare you to printf("%o", num) :-)

Comment: @AllanWind I'll post my code for 10 minutes as an alternate answer... :-)